# Dot notation with dates

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to understand how q defines dot notation for dates.

**Case 1: Temporal Variable Issue**

For ex. if I do following to get day from a date:

```
q) d:2014.06.14

q) d.dd   
  14 i
```

But if I try doing this without any temporal variable:

```
q) (2014.06.14).dd

 Error: .dd
```

**Question**: **Why it requires a variable to apply dot notation.**

**Case 2: Inside Functions:**

Dot notation with date doesn't work inside functions.

```
q) {x.mm}[2014.01.01]

Error: x.mm
```

Solution for that is casting

```
q){`mm$x}[2014.01.01]  
  1i
```

**Question: Why temporal variable property doesn't work inside function?**

I want to understand the behaviour of dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation only applies to things with "names" in the sense of belonging to the workspace tree (and to columns in qsql queries). Essentially, if you can't say `` get`a `` successfully, you won't be able to say `a.dd` either.

Answer (score 0):

All valid questions with some vague answers :)

**Case 1: Temporal Variable Issue/Question: Why it requires a variable to apply dot notation.**

Dot notation is not a construct that you can use like in other languages. It's a quick way to get at the integer components of a date written into the compiler (i.e. I suspect the compiler is probably just looking for [date]. and nothing more complex).

**Case 2: Inside Functions/Question: Why temporal variable property doesn't work inside function?:**

Dot notation is not meant to be used inside functions. Has been the case for a long time, although I've never heard a sound explanation as to why.

Comment: Thanks but still it requires more investigation . I know this concept is not very clear and there is not enough resources available online.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading this somewhere on code.kx:

http://code.kx.com/q4m3/2_Basic_Data_Types_Atoms/#257-constituents-and-dot-notation

> **Advanced:** It is a quirk in q that dot notation for accessing temporal
>   constituents does not work on function arguments.

I suppose accessing constituents of date or time variable has its own limitations in a local variable VS a global variable.

Comment: Ok so that explains case 2 for some extent(no solid explanation there for this behavior)  but what about case 1?

Comment: imo, a raw object by itself won't have much special properties build on itself, it will just be an object with a certain object type, nothing more. But by assigning an object to a variable, there might be a background job that q does to put addition properties to the variable (like these constituents). I hope this opinion is valid enough though :P

Comment: @rahul, I think your best bet is to stick to casting (`date$`month etc...) since that will always work

Comment: @WooiKent: I think you are right in some way. That's what I am trying to figure out that what q does internally.

Comment: @JPC: I know casting works but just trying to understand these concepts.

Comment: @Rahul, that's fair. Didn't mean to imply the question wasn't good or that you shouldn't want to know, just wanted to give a 1-size-fits-all alternative